# How to Force Oracle to Resolve IN Subquery First

Tags: oracle

I have a view (V_STUFF_WE_SELL) in an Oracle 11g database containing a complex group by.
Querying from this view is reasonably fast in most circumstances, but if I try to query with an IN subquery, it takes a very long time. (Note that the hard-coded org_id value would be normally be a parameter coming from the user application.)

```
Select * from V_STUFF_WE_SELL s where s.STUFF_WE_SELL_ID in
   (Select stuff_we_sell_id from aprov_item a where a.org_id = 1) --this takes way too long
```

However, If I substitute the values that result from the subquery, the query takes <1 second.

```
Select * from V_STUFF_WE_SELL s where s.STUFF_WE_SELL_ID in (100, 200) --this is very fast
```

Running the subquery by itself is also very fast (<1 second). How can I force Oracle to resolve the subquery first? I tried hints such as push_subq to no avail.

**Edit:** Here is the explain plan for the query

```
Select * from V_STUFF_WE_SELL s where s.STUFF_WE_SELL_ID in
   (Select /*+ no_merge*/  stuff_we_sell_id from aprov_item a where a.org_id = 1)
```

The view "V_STUFF_WE_SELL" is complex...

[image: V_STUFF_WE_SELL EXPLAIN PLAN]

**Edit 2:** I incorrectly assumed that the remote joins were the problem; rather, it was the grouping on the view. The IN query block slowness issue still remains, however. The given answers do not work for me.
While I was hoping to avoid user application changes, that might be my best option.

Comment: @AlexPoole the subquery is coming from the user application. Turning it into a join would require application changes. aprov_item is local.

Comment: How do you know the "subquery" is not evaluated first already? What did you see in the execution plan? If you see the "subquery" merged into the view evaluation, you can try the `/*+ no_merge */` hint; but rather than guessing, it would be more efficient to figure out what the optimizer is doing, so you can tell it not to do it.

Comment: @mathguy Please see my edit. Am I using the no_merge hint correctly?

Comment: You are using the hint correctly. The plan shows that the subquery is unnested (moved from the `where` clause to the `from` section). See what happens if you use the `no_unnest` hint (instead of `no_merge`).

Answer (score 2):

You may try to instruct the optimizer to run the join on remote side with `/*+driving_site*/` [hint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-DDABFD2E-FE80-4A2D-99D2-87E61EFA2182). For this you need to enable view merging by removing `no_merge` and specify an alias of the table inside the view where `stuff_we_sell_id` comes from. See [`tablespec`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF51098) (surprisingly, it has more detailed description in old documentation).

Assuming `stuff_we_sell_id` is from `stuff_we_sell` and it uses alias `sws` and it is located at the top level `select` in the view definition for `V_STUFF_WE_SELL`, it should be for your query:

```
/*+driving_side(s.swf)*/
```

As a last resort you may also use `/*+precompute_subquery*/` hint to turn the query results into static list. Though, it is not described in the documentation.

```
SQL> explain plan set statement_id = 'DIRECT IN' for
  2  select *
  3  from t1
  4  where id in (
  5    select f.id
  6    from t2 f
  7    where f.val = 2
  8  );

Explained.

SQL> 
SQL> select *
  2  from table(dbms_xplan.display(
  3    statement_id => 'DIRECT IN'
  4    , format => 'BASIC +PREDICATE'
  5  ));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
-----------------------
Plan hash value: 1713220790
 
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name                       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                            |
|   1 |  RESULT CACHE               | 7p34pbmcbag2k8nxm2mmdaf1xj |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN SEMI            |                            |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| T1                         |
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| T2                         |
------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("ID"="F"."ID")
   4 - storage("F"."VAL"=2)
       filter("F"."VAL"=2)
 
Result Cache Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------------------
   1 - 

23 rows selected.
```

And with hint you may see a direct constant filter. Of course, this will be a subject to general `in` restrictions like 1000 items.

```
SQL> 
SQL> explain plan set statement_id = 'PRECOMPUTE IN' for
  2  select *
  3  from t1
  4  where id in (
  5    select /*+precompute_subquery*/ f.id
  6    from t2 f
  7    where f.val = 2
  8  );

Explained.

SQL> 
SQL> select *
  2  from table(dbms_xplan.display(
  3    statement_id => 'PRECOMPUTE IN'
  4    , format => 'BASIC +PREDICATE'
  5  ));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
--------------------------
Plan hash value: 3617692013
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                            |
|   1 |  RESULT CACHE              | 9fhujgv4hsjgq5xy5a4zv90nys |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| T1                         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
   2 - storage("ID"=2 OR "ID"=5)
       filter("ID"=2 OR "ID"=5)
 
Result Cache Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - 

20 rows selected.
```

[*livesql demo*](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/l3z2a11pzgc5ae6nr1pa6uadu)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this sounds like what I want, but is it possible precompute_subquery does not work in 11g? The hint makes no difference in the explain plans...

Comment: @sql_dru I've used it in 11g, so should work. Please, provide a query text.

Comment: The query "Select  * from V_STUFF_WE_SELL s where s.STUFF_WE_SELL_ID in
       (Select /*+ precompute_subquery*/ stuff_we_sell_id from aprov_item a where a.org_id = 57633)" has an identical explain plan whether or not the hint is there.

Comment: I was able to get precompute_subquery working with other queries. It seems Oracle ignores the hint sometimes...

Comment: I found this inconclusive discussion by someone having the same issue as me. https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2350855/precompute-subquery-hint

Comment: @sql_dru Looks like 10053 trace should be taken to find out why optimizer decided to ignore the hint.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use EXISTS operator -

```
SELECT *
  FROM V_STUFF_WE_SELL S
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM aprov_item A
                WHERE A.org_id = 1
                  AND S.STUFF_WE_SELL_ID = A.stuff_we_sell_id);
```

Comment: In principle, the `exists` and the `in` syntax will result in the same execution plan. If this does, in fact, help, it likely exposes something really odd about the OP's setup.

Comment: Unfortunately, mathguy is correct. This results in the same execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

The `Explain Plan` shows that the optimizer unnests the subquery in the `where` clause (it moves it to the `from` clause). To prevent it from doing so - to force it to compute the subquery separately and use it as a filter in the `where` clause - you can use the `no_unnest` hint, like so:

```
Select * from V_STUFF_WE_SELL s where s.STUFF_WE_SELL_ID in
   (Select /*+ no_unnest */ stuff_we_sell_id from aprov_item a where a.org_id = 1);
```

Alternatively - as a good programming practice - you may want to keep all the hints together at the top of the query, in the main `select` statement. To do so, you need to name the subquery (technically: **query block**) and reference it in the hint. Notice the syntax: the hint to name the query block (the `qb_name` hint) and the reference to it in the hint at the main level (name preceded by `@`):

```
Select /*+ no_unnest(@subq) */ * from V_STUFF_WE_SELL s where s.STUFF_WE_SELL_ID in
(Select /*+ qb_name(subq) */ stuff_we_sell_id from aprov_item a where a.org_id = 1)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the answers above didn't work for me.

A different approach was to try joining in directly the sub-query with DISTINCT. In my situation Oracle then chose a better order and a 4 minute query was transformed into 4 seconds.

```
Select s.* 
  from V_STUFF_WE_SELL s 
     , (Select DISTINCT stuff_we_sell_id from aprov_item a where a.org_id = 1) i
 where s.STUFF_WE_SELL_ID = i.stuff_we_sell_id;
```